# how to merge two nested dictionaries under a same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, array-merge

for example I have a dictionary:

```
dictA={"nest1":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[1,7,8,9,10]},
       "nest2":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[6,4,8,10,10]}}
```

the list inside has the same length. I need to merge *nest1* and *nest2* as one dictionary, and the result should be like this:

```
dictA={"nest":{"01feb":[2,4,6,8,10],"02feb":[7,11,16,19,20]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese find the below code for your query.

```
dictA={"nest1":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[1,7,8,9,10]},
       "nest2":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[6,4,8,10,10]}}
result ={}
final_op = {}
for k,v in dictA.iteritems():
    for nk,nv in v.iteritems():
        if result.has_key(nk):
            i=0
            while i < len(result[nk]):
                result[nk][i] += nv[i]
                i += 1
        else:
            result[nk] = nv
final_op['nest'] = result
print final_op
```

Output:

```
{'nest': {'02feb': [7, 11, 16, 19, 20], '01feb': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I tried your code and it is exactly what I need in my application. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict), [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#zip) like this example (works with Python 2 and Python 3).

```
dictA = {'nest1': {'01feb': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '02feb': [1, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
 'nest2': {'01feb': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '02feb': [6, 4, 8, 10, 10]}}

a = (v.items() for _, v in map(list, dictA.items()))
# You can also use another map():
# final = {'nest': {k: list(map(sum, zip(v,j))) for (k, v), (_, j) in zip(*a)}}
final = {'nest': {k: [m+n for m, n in zip(v, j)] for (k, v), (_, j) in zip(*a)}}

print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'nest': {'02feb': [7, 11, 16, 19, 20], '01feb': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}}
```

Comment: this should be the best answer, thanks for your pythonic way!

Comment: You can do it in one line, too,  if you want. Cheers and happy coding :)

Comment: This requires `dictA` to have two keys exactly. It breaks with less or more entries in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes @HeikoOberdiek . This answer will work only with a dict  similar to OP's dict.

Answer (score 1):

You have to traverse the dict and update the value in the iteration.

```
dictA={"nest1":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[1,7,8,9,10]},
       "nest2":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[6,4,8,10,10]}}

def merge(dictA):
    merge_dict = {}
    for key in dictA:
        for sub_key in dictA[key]:
            if sub_key in merge_dict:
                # update the nested value
                merge_dict[sub_key] = [sum(x) for x in zip(*[merge_dict[sub_key], dictA[key][sub_key]])]
            else:
                merge_dict[sub_key] = dictA[key][sub_key]
    return merge_dict

merge_dict = merge(dictA)
dictA.clear()
dictA["nest"] = merge_dict

print(dictA)
```

Comment: thank you soo much for your idea, this is really python. I will definitely give you an up! while i can only give one answer as accepted, my friend.

Comment: My pleasure. It's OK :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to do what you're asking for:

```
def merge_nested(dictionary):
    result = dict()
    for nested in dictionary.values():
        for key in nested.keys():
            if key in result:
                # We've already found it, add our values to it's
                for i in range(len(result[key])):
                    result[key][i] += nested[key][i]
            else:
                result[key] = nested[key]
    return {"nest":result}
```

With this function you get the following output:

```
>>> print(merge_nested({"nest1":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[1,7,8,9,10]},"nest2":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[6,4,8,10,10]}}))
{'nest': {'01feb': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], '02feb': [7, 11, 16, 19, 20]}}
```

This is a modified version of @Arockia's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601353/7246614)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `groupby` of `itertools`:

```python
from itertools import chain, groupby
import operator

dictA={"nest1":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[1,7,8,9,10]},
       "nest2":{"01feb":[1,2,3,4,5],"02feb":[6,4,8,10,10]}}

A = {
    "nest": dict(
        (key, list(map(operator.add, *(v for _, v in group))))
        for key, group in groupby(
            sorted(
                chain(*(v.iteritems() for v in dictA.values()))  # Python 2
                # chain(*(v.items() for v in dictA.values()))    # Python 3
            ),
            lambda x: x[0],
        )
    )
}

print(A)
```

Result:

```python
{'nest': {'02feb': [7, 11, 16, 19, 20], '01feb': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}}
```