# merge multiple nested dictionaries under a same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, array-merge

for example there is dicA

```
dicA = {"01Feb":{"a":{"M1":[2,1,3,3],
                  "M2":[3,5,7,9],
                  "L3":[1,1,1,1]
                  },
            "b":{"M1":[2,4,8,1],
                 "M2":[1,1,2,0],
                 "L3":[3,4,6,8]}
                 },
    "02Feb":{"a":{"M1":[2,3,1,1],
                  "M2":[6,5,6,9]
                 },
             "b":{"M1":[2,4,8,1],
                  "M2":[1,1,2,0],
                  "L3":[3,4,6,8]
                  },
             "c":{"M1":[2,3,1,1],
                  "M2":[6,5,6,9],
                  "L3":[0,0,1,1]}
                  },
    "03Feb":{"a":{"M1":[3,3,3,3],
                  "M2":[5,5,7,7],
                  "L3":[3,3,3,3]}
                  }}
```

this is little bit complicated for me, the list inside has the same length.
I want to merge M1 and M2 as M, while just keep L3. It should be like this:

```
dicA = {{"01Feb":{"a":{"M":[5,6,10,12]},                  
                      {"L3":[1,1,1,1]}},
                 {"b":{"M":[3,5,10,1]},
                      {"L3":[3,4,6,8]}}},
        {"02Feb":{"a":{"M":[8,8,7,10]}},
                 {"b":{"M":[3,5,10,1]},
                      {"L3":[3,4,6,8]}},
                 {"c":{"M":[8,8,7,10]},
                      {"L3":[0,0,1,1]}}},
        {"03Feb":{"a":{"M":[8,8,10,10]},
                      {"L3":[3,3,3,3]}}}}
```

Then, I want to merge 'a','b' and 'c'. It should like this finally:

```
dicA = {{"01Feb":{"M":[8,11,20,13]},                  
                 {"L3":[4,5,7,9]}},
        {"02Feb":{"M":[19,21,24,21]},
                 {"L3":[3,4,7,9]}},
        {"03Feb":{"M":[8,8,10,10]},
                 {"L3":[3,3,3,3]}}}
```

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601474/5496463..it is same as your questions but more simpler.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `dicA` is invalid: you can not have such notation `"a":{"M1":[2,1,3,3]},
                      {"M2":[3,5,7,9]},
                      {"L3":[1,1,1,1]}` in Python. Do change your input

Comment: @danche yep, but i found some problems which I may have C or D more conditions in this situation.

Comment: @Field.D you just need to add one more iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I post a similar question before, so you guys may think this is same question. Actually it is a different question which needs to merge **multiple nested Dictionaries with Different keys**. the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601256/how-to-merge-two-nested-dictionaries-under-a-same-dictionary) in the comments is show how to merge **multiple nested Dictionaries with Same keys**.

Here is my solution to combine merge these two situations in this case.

```
def merge(dictF):

#create two new dict 
   M_12_merge ={}
  abc_merge={}
  for key in dictF:
      M_12_merge[key]={}
      abc_merge[key]={}
  for key in dictF:
      for subKey in dictF[key]:
          M_12_merge[key][subKey]={}

  for rekey in M_12_merge:
      for sub_rekey in M_12_merge[rekey]:
          M_12_merge[rekey][sub_rekey]['M']=[]

# 1. merge sub_sub_key 'M1' and 'M2' under different keys
  for key in dictF:
      for sub_key in dictF[key]:
          numberList=[]
          for sub_sub_key in dictF[key][sub_key]:
              if 'M' in sub_sub_key:
                  numberList.append(dictF[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key])
              else:
                  M_12_merge[key][subKey][sub_sub_key]=dictF[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key]
          M_12_merge[key][sub_key]['M']=map(sum,zip(*numberList))      

# 2. merge sub_key 'a','b' and 'c' under same keys
  for key in M_12_merge:
      for sub_key in M_12_merge[key]:
          for sub_sub_key in M_12_merge[key][sub_key]:
              if sub_sub_key in abc_merge[key]:
                  abc_merge[key][sub_sub_key] = [sum(x) for x in zip(*[abc_merge[key][sub_sub_key], M_12_merge[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key]])]
              else:
                  abc_merge[key][sub_sub_key] = M_12_merge[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key]                
  return abc_merge


dic = merge(dicA) 
print(dic)
```

Thanks people who vote this question down. Hope this solution can help people who need it. Also, any new ideas is welcomed for this case.

Regards,

D