# How to combine recurring nested dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary of dictionaries:

```py
[
            {
                "eid_number": "984000714187062",
                "hours": 0,
                "management_id": "9",
                "outings": {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T18:00:00Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "eid_number": "984000714187088",
                "hours": 12.0,
                "management_id": "8",
                "outings": {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T09:03:26Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "eid_number": "984000714187088",
                "hours": 12.0,
                "management_id": "8",
                "outings": {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T06:00:00Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
                }
            },
            {
                "eid_number": "984000714190010",
                "hours": 6.0,
                "management_id": "13",
                "outings": {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T06:00:00Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
                }
            }
        ]
```

The cow with eid_number that ends with 7088 has two objects.
I'm looking for a way to combine the two dictionaries.

but I need the nested **outings** dictionary to be updated into a list containing the merged dictionaries values.

```py
[
            # Rest of object from before ...
            {
                "eid_number": "984000714187088",
                "hours": 12.0,
                "management_id": "8",
                "outings":[
                {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T09:03:26Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "out": "2020-09-05T06:00:00Z",
                    "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
                }
              ]
            },
          # Rest of object from before ...
        ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to merge two nested dictionaries under a same dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601256/how-to-merge-two-nested-dictionaries-under-a-same-dictionary)

Comment: It is not clear that if there are only one element in `outings`.Should it be a single dict or list with only one dict?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it should be a list containing dictionaries of outings from the combined dictionaries

Comment: @EdwardRomero this would not do in my case

Comment: The `hours` property would need to be summed for duplicate `eid_numbers`?

Comment: @Rfroes87 no, I'm only interested in the outings, the rest of the properties are exact duplicates always

Comment: You don't have a dictionary of dictionaries—you have a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give another option, here's my take:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [
    {
        "eid_number": "984000714187062",
        "hours": 0,
        "management_id": "9",
        "outings": {
            "out": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z",
            "_in": "2020-09-05T18:00:00Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "eid_number": "984000714187088",
        "hours": 12.0,
        "management_id": "8",
        "outings": {
            "out": "2020-09-05T09:03:26Z",
            "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "eid_number": "984000714187088",
        "hours": 12.0,
        "management_id": "8",
        "outings": {
            "out": "2020-09-05T06:00:00Z",
            "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "eid_number": "984000714190010",
        "hours": 6.0,
        "management_id": "13",
        "outings": {
            "out": "2020-09-05T06:00:00Z",
            "_in": "2020-09-05T12:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]

temp_dict = defaultdict(list)

for d in l:
 o = d.pop("outings")
 temp_dict[tuple(d.values())].append(o)

r = [{'eid_number': eid_number, 'hours': hours, 'management_id': management_id, 'outings': outings} for (eid_number, hours, management_id), outings in temp_dict.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for i in data:
    outings = i.pop('outings')
    if i['eid_number'] not in result:
        result[i['eid_number']] = {**i, 'outings': []}
    result[i['eid_number']]['outings'].append(outings)
        
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'eid_number': '984000714187062',
  'hours': 0,
  'management_id': '9',
  'outings': [{'_in': '2020-09-05T18:00:00Z', 'out': '2020-09-05T12:00:00Z'}]},
 {'eid_number': '984000714187088',
  'hours': 12.0,
  'management_id': '8',
  'outings': [{'_in': '2020-09-05T12:00:00Z', 'out': '2020-09-05T09:03:26Z'},
              {'_in': '2020-09-05T12:00:00Z', 'out': '2020-09-05T06:00:00Z'}]},
 {'eid_number': '984000714190010',
  'hours': 6.0,
  'management_id': '13',
  'outings': [{'_in': '2020-09-05T12:00:00Z', 'out': '2020-09-05T06:00:00Z'}]}]
```